# How to create the same google documentation custom dialog example of text message limit?

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

I'd want to create exactly the same custom dialog that you can find on Google documentation.

The dialog is this one:

[image: Text Limit Dialog of Documentation]

How I can do?

I need this dialog because I want that users can choose an integer to use it for something in my app.

Please help me.

I need exactly the same dialog.

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you tried something and failed?

Comment: I don't understand how to implement that scroll list....

Comment: I dont feel the question is irrelevant, as even I wan not aware about the numberPicker name , so the search was with the exact title. So +1 for helping to find the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not a scroll list. It's a `NumberPicker`. You'll need API 11+ to implement this.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html